# Is there an easier way to autofill a column in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Title. Is there a faster way to autofill a column or row in google sheets instead of dragging down? I have a 50,000 entries down a column and if there's a faster way than dragging down the column, I would love to know!

Comment: Most often, a single array formula can fill an entire column. If you can provide more information (ideally a link to your sheet, even if only with "View only" permission) and an indication of which column holds the current row-by-row formula, I or someone else here can likely suggest such a formula. At the very least, we'd need you to provide the in your post the current formula that you're trying to drag down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double click the bottom right of the cell with the formula.